# Which one reacts first with NaOH; Triglycerides or FFA?

Tags: saponification

I want to saponify Crude Palm Oil (CPO) with NaOH. The CPO itself contains 97,35% of triglycerides and 2,5% of free fatty acids. Which one reacts first with NaOH?

Comment: The free acids will react first with the NaOH to form the salt (soap)

Comment: If there is still some FFA, there is no NaOH yet. If there is already some NaOH, there is no FFA anymore and NaOH can finally start the long awaited and slow saponifying.

Answer (score 2):

Triglycerides require nucleophilic displacement of the glycerin component, whereas FFAs require only deprotonation. The latter is much faster.